# Bizarre behaviour with NSTimer

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, nsoperationqueue, core-motion

I cannot seem to work this one out. Here is my set up:

I have a function called `requestDataWithCompletion:(someBlock)block`. I call it when the class is initialised. The function requests certain motion data. I want to do this periodically, therefore, the first time I call this function, I specify some completion code which sets up a timer that re-calls this function periodically. The timer calls it via another function `requestDataWithoutCompletion` which simply calls the `requestDataWithCompletion` but with an empty block (so I don't keep creating timers);

```
- (void) requestDataWithCompletion:(someBlock)block {
// BREAK POINT 1
        [self.motionManager queryActivityStartingFromDate:start toDate:[NSDate date] toQueue:self.queue withHandler:^(NSArray *activities, NSError *error) { 
// BREAK POINT 2
            // do some processing; 
            block();
        }];
    }
```

The block simply creates a timer on the main queue, which periodically recalls this function, but with no completion (since I don't want to keep creating more timers).

```
block = ^{
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timerInterval 
target:self selector:@selector(requestDataWithoutCompletion) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
            });
    }

- (void) requestDataWithoutCompletion {
[self requestDataWithCompletion^{;}];
}
```

The amazing thing is that despite this set up, my app is creating timer after timer! I can't understand why.

I have placed break points in `requestDataWithCompletion` method. One is outside the block submitted to `NSOperationQueue` to get activity data (BREAKPOINT 1) and one is inside the block submitted to `NSOperationQueue.` (BREAKPOINT 2). Basically it shows that each time the method is called by the timer, BREAKPOINT 1 has an empty completion block (as it should be) but then strangely BREAKPOINT 2 has the completion block I submitted when I first called the function when initialising the class. Therefore, it continues to create a new timer each time the function is called by the timer. Over time, this means a massive number of timers and then the app crashes!

I have a feeling this is something to do with NSOperationQueue, but I really don't know what it could be.

Comment: why not create the timer in the first place?

Comment: It's basically because I don't know when the query for motion data might return but I want to call it straight away

Comment: So you want `timerInterval` seconds between actually receiving the data, rather than asking for the data? Because with this code you'll get that the first time only.

Comment: No I want timerInterval between asking for the data. This code is supposed to work like... request data first time -> data comes back -> set up timer -> [timerInterval] -> request data again -> data comes back -> [timerInterval] -> etc.  Unfortunately, each time the data comes back it creates a new timer

Comment: The way you have it at the moment is: request data first time -> data comes back -> set up timer -> [timerInterval] -> request data -> [timerInterval] -> request data -> [timerInterval] -> request data -> etc. With the data coming back in parallel to that chain.

Comment: True, but the data does tend to come back straight away and the timerInterval is 15s so effectively it becomes the pattern I described. What mystifies me though is why the timers keep getting made again and again. Ive accepted your answers, it simplifies things!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your initialisation (or when you first want to get the data and then continue getting it):

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timerInterval target:self selector:@selector(requestDataWithoutCompletion) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[self.timer fire]; //get the activity data immediately. 

- (void) requestDataWithoutCompletion {
    [self requestDataWithCompletion:^{}];
}
```

With your original `requestDataWithCompletion:` method. (though you could get rid of `requestDataWithCompletion:` and put it's code directly in `requestDataWithoutCompletion` if you're not using it elsewhere)